# Excel C# AutoFilter For Each not looping correctly

Tags: c#, foreach, excel-interop

I've been working to convert an excel Macro I had into a C# winform app to make it easier for others to use. However, I'm getting stuck on the foreach statement needed for the worksheet. Basically, we get a worksheet of all of the customers data we have and the excel macro filters the data by unique customer identified (Column AA), copies the visible cells and pastes it onto a new worksheet. I've got the autofilter to get to the first cell in AA, but it won't move to the next one, it keeps copying and pasting the first customer onto an infinite number of new sheets. I'm not really sure how to get the AutoFilter criteria to move to AA3 instead of staying stuck on AA2.

```
            fullRow3 = newerWSCopy.Range["AA:AA"].Rows.Count;
            lastRow4 = newerWSCopy.Cells[fullRow3, "AA"].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
            Excel.Range machine2 = newerWSCopy.Range["AA2:AA" + lastRow4];
            Excel.Range visibleCells = newerWSCopy.Range["A1:I" + lastRow3].SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Type.Missing);
            

            foreach (var facility in newerWSCopy.Range["AA2:AA" + lastRow4])
            {
                
                    newerWSCopy.Range["A1:I" + lastRow3].AutoFilter(3,machine2.Value, XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues, Type.Missing, true);
                    newerWSCopy.AutoFilter.Range.Copy();
                    Excel.Worksheet newWS = xlApp2.Worksheets.Add(After: xlWorkbook2.Sheets[xlWorkbook2.Sheets.Count]);
                    newWS.AutoFilterMode = false;
                    newWS.Paste();

            }
```

I've tried changing the AutoFilter criteria but can't get anything that sticks.

Comment: You probably should write `foreach (var facility in newerWSCopy.Range["AA2:AA" + lastRow4].Cells)`. And you seem not to use `facility` in your loop.

Comment: That worked!! Thank you so much! I ended up changing the facility to Range Facility and then the autofilter criteria to facility. Thanks again!